# socketserver TCPServer not working

Tags: python

According to the code on the book, I used `TCPServer` to create a TCP server and overrite the `handle()`.
After build the connection, the server will print `'connected:'` and `client address`.
but when I `self.wfile.write()` to send the data, either the server and client can't receive the data.

**code of server:**

```
from socketserver import (TCPServer as TCP, StreamRequestHandler as SRH) 


HOST = ''
PORT = 1235
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)


class MyRequestHandler(SRH):
    def handle(self):
        print('connected:', self.client_address)
        self.wfile.write('kkk'.encode('utf-8'))


tcpServ = TCP(ADDR, MyRequestHandler)
print('waiting for connection...')

tcpServ.serve_forever()
```

**code of client:**

```
from socket import *


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1235
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

while True:
    tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
    data = input('>')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data.encode("utf-8"))
    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE).decode("utf-8")
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)
    tcpCliSock.close()
```

Comment: Try to first receive the data from the client with something like `buffer = self.request.recv(1024)` before writing into the stream.

Comment: now i use below code to receive the data from client and print:
        self.content = self.rfile.readline()
        print(self.content.decode())
but the data was printed after the client break, any guys knows why?

Comment: I would recommend to start off with the `BaseRequestHandler` and use the attribute `request` with its methods `recv` and `send`.